# Issues reading a .txt file in Java

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm a java newbie looking for some help reading a file. Here is the code I am using.

source:

```
public void Escanear()
{

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("inicio.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        String token = sc.next();

        if (token.equals("Pared"))
        {
            int i=sc.nextInt();
            int j=sc.nextInt();

            _mat=new Pared[i][j];
        }

        else if(token.equals("Fantasma"))
        {
            int i=sc.nextInt();
            int j=sc.nextInt();

            _mat=new Fantasma[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Jorge\Clases UNIMET\Trimestre 5\Estructuras de Datos\Proyecto Pacman\JuegoPacman.java:28: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("inicio.txt"));
```

I've imported java.io.FileNotFoundException, and I've already opened the .txt file, which is located in the same folder as the class I'm compiling... Any idea of how can it be fixed? THANKS.

Comment: Give the proper path. Like `D:/jmd/sample.log`.

Comment: Please post the full path to the file here, does it contain any national symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` is a **compilation error**. It means that one of the method calls in your code is declared to throw a FileNotFoundException.

It is not related to the location of the file because your program doesn't  even get executed.

[Scanner constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) that you call on line 28 is declared to potentially throw a FileNotFoundException.

This means that you need to handle this potentially thrown exception. Either by adding `throws FileNotFoundException` to your Escanear method definition (which shouldn't start with capital letter btw), or by surrounding the line with this method call with `try-catch`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch or throw the FileNotFoundException on to get it to compile.

Example:

```
Scanner sc;
try {
  sc = new Scanner(new File("inicio.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say in a comment:

> The thing is that when I give it the full path name, it shows 9
>   illegal escape character errors

This is probably due to a path in your source code like:

```
"foo\dir\myfile.txt"
```

You must escape the backslashes to make this legal Java:

```
"foo\\dir\\myfile.txt"
```

(Or use forward slashes - I think this works fine even on Windows)

Java thinks that `\d` and `\m` are intended as special characters encoded as *escape sequences*.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html for a list of legal escape sequences such as `\n` for newline.

Comment: already solved it with throws FileNotFoundException, thanks anyways.